# Will it be a constraint for App approval by AppStore?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, appstore-approval

I am considering to customize the UIAlert view in my application.I want to show corresponding image,along with the message, in my alert view according to the situation(like error,warning etc), when i am showing the alert to the user.I am not going to extend my customized alert view from UIAlertView (and i am not sure it is possible) instead it will be from standard UIView with required methods as per my requirements.Will the apple reject my app if i change the look and feel of the alert functionality?

Comment: @Hariprased - Please consider joining the [App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) proposal on Area 51.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so... There are thousands of ways to present the user some kind of alert. If it is a UIAlertView or a custom view, I don't think Apple will reject our app for that...

Comment: Thank you for giving me the hope.I will present my alert in a customized manner in app.